# Error 404 al intentar visualizar documento WSDL web services

Tags: java, webservice, soap, wsdl, 404

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente servicio de prueba mediante el servidor Apache Tomcat version 90.78, al momento de colocar la uri:`http://localhost:8080/WebService1/WS100?WSDL` no me esta dejando ver el contrato WSDL y me envia un error 404 desconocido, ya revise el servidor , los logs , entre otros factores pero no se que mas pueda hacer respecto al tema, que puedo hacer?.

WS100.java

```
package com.empresa.proyecto.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;


@WebService(serviceName = "WS100")
public class WS100 {

   
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getMensaje")
    public String getMensaje(@WebParam(name = "code") String code) {
        String msg = "Bienvenido a web service - SOAP:" + code; 
        System.out.println(code);
        return msg;
        
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/WebService1"/>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]